# Finding file and replacing word with some specific word

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Find some specific file and then once a file is found, I want some specific word in it and then replace it with finding word with a new one. Can I do it with a single line?

For example, I want to find a file 'file.txt' and in that file want to search `read` and replace it with `write` using a single-line command.

Comment: Please give a specific example with complete input and desired output. It's hard to understand what you mean if you word it so general.

Comment: I have edited my question and add what I exactly want .

Comment: I have tried below answer that work for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Execute:

```
find -type f -name "specificFileName" -exec sed -i.bak 's/foundWord/replaceWithWord/' '{}' \;
```

This will only replace first seen 'foundWord' with 'replaceWithWord', in case you wanted to replace all these 'foundWord's add sed's "g" enabler to having replace all seen

```
find -type f -name "specificFileName" -exec sed -i.bak 's/foundWord/replaceWithWord/g' '{}' \;
```

note: This will copies the 'specificFileName's as their backup files and name them with "specificFileName.bak", by dropping the "-i.bak" you will tell 'sed' to inplace replace,

Comment: You should mention that this copies the original file to `filename.bak` as backup first. But +1 for the correct answer to this originally vague question.

Comment: Can it changed both the file of the same name in different folder ?

Comment: I want to say , suppose in a directory there are two folders containing the same file name , then will it affect both of them ?

Comment: pwd, will print your current path of working directory, if you run this given command in this directory path it will find all "specificFileName" files in current + all sub-directories in each level of depth